# Why the period of $\cos(2iz+13)$ is $i\pi$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My teacher said without explaining that since the period of $\cos(z)$ is $2\pi$ then the period of $\cos(2iz+13)$? is $i\pi$. Why is this true?

Comment: Try expanding out $\cos(2i(z+i\pi)+13)$.

Comment: Generalize the result to make it easier: if $f$ has period $p$ then $g$ defined by $g(x)=f(ax+b)$ with $a\ne0$ has period $p/a$. Now your proof!

Comment: As an aside, the use of the article 'the' implies uniqueness of a period. This isn't right. In this context there are infinite periods.

Comment: @Git, right; the teacher ought to have spoken of "minimal periods"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that the function $\cos z $ is $2\pi $ periodic. Let the period of $\cos (2iz+13) $ be $k $. Since $$\cos [2i (z+k)+13]=\cos [2iz +13+2ik]$$ it follows that $2ik =2\pi \Rightarrow k=-i\pi $ and hence the required period $k $ is $i\pi $. Hope it helps.